# I broke my WordPress functions.php (Wordpress, PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

it seems like I broke my Wordpress functions.php.
When editing Posts or Products (Woocommerce), here's the error I'm getting:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/web22959994/html/repair/wp-content/themes/freestore-child/functions.php:24) in /var/www/web22959994/html/repair/wp-admin/post.php on line 197

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/web22959994/html/repair/wp-content/themes/freestore-child/functions.php:24) in /var/www/web22959994/html/repair/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179
```

As the error says, the problem seems to be in the functions.php. I have confirmed that by emptying it out completely, which resolves the error. 
Here's my functions.php:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'freestore'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 16;' ), 20 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price' );
function hide_free_price($price){
return ('Ab 99');
};
?>
```

I've ran it through some PHP checkers and haven't found an issue. Most of it is pretty basic stuff (enqueing a style for the child theme, editing some small functions via filter). However it seems to be broken and I personally don't know why.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have any whitespace before or after the php tags?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed I did. Removed it and it was fixed. Totally my bad there. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's considered best practice to omit the closing php tag at the end of the php files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, guess i made a complete a** out of myself. I had two extra lines after the closing tag. Issue is fixed.